# Changing Prompt on pxssh - could not synchronize with original prompt error

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm testing pxssh with Oracle VM CLI and got the following error.

```
>>> s = pxssh.pxssh()
>>> s.login('xxxx', 'xxx', password='xxx', port=10000)   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>",
 line 1, in <module>   File
 "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 317, in login
      raise ExceptionPxssh('could not synchronize with original prompt')
      pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: could not synchronize with original prompt
```

It works fine using manual openssh session so I thought could be due to default prompt which is 'OVM>' but setting the "original_prompt='[OVM>]'" doesn't work as well.

Working openssh session.

```
login as: ovmadmin
ovmadmin@xxxxx's password:
OVM>
```

Appreciate any tips/helps.
Lupin

Comment: What about setting `original_prompt='OVM>'`, i.e. without the []? It's a regex, so the square brackets make it a character class.

Comment: No joy. s.login('xxxxx', 'xxxx',password='xxxx',original_prompt='OVM>', port=10000,auto_prompt_reset=False)
raise ExceptionPxssh('could not synchronize with original prompt')
pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: could not synchronize with original prompt. Guess time to give and resort to paramiko.:)